# Is it possible to configure HTTP request timeout from outside the application in cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, http, connection-timeout

I had Mac application in which it has some Client - Server communications. I set the default HTTP request timeout as 60 seconds in the app. Is it possible to configure HTTP request timeout from outside of the application?
Any suggestions...

Comment: You can get the value for the timeout from the server every time app opens. Single endpoint that returns the timeout and you can save it in NSUserDefaults until the next app runs.